# Proof of strong Markov property for non finite-valued stopping times

Tags: stochastic-processes, markov-chains, stopping-times

I have this proof about the strong Markov property but it does only hold for finite-valued stopping times. Is it possible to modify it at some points s.t. it holds for any stopping time $\tau$ with values in $\mathbb{N}\cup \{\infty\}$??

[image]

Comment: What should the *statement* even be if $\tau$ is allowed to be $\infty$?

Comment: You are right, I need to reformulate the statement first...